# Assign a workbook range to a variable - Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I have declared my variable as a `Range`:

```
Dim CheckAnnex As Range
```

and the following line gives a type mismatch:

```
set CheckAnnex = Workbooks("File.xlsm").Worksheets("Main").Range("H7:H28")
```

Comment: Do you have a class of your own named Range? Do you have the Word library referenced? What happens when you position the caret on the word `Range` and press Shift+F2?

Comment: If I put the cursor in the Range keyword in the line set CheckAnnex = Workbooks("File.xlsm").Worksheets("Main").Range("H7:H28") and click Shift+F2  I got an error message 'Identifier under cursor is not recognized'

Comment: I meant in the `Dim CheckAnnex As Range`.

Comment: No Library Referenced, no class named Range

Comment: Where the declaration in discussion is made? In the same sub trying to set the variable?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer.  When I click on Range, it goes to the list of members of the worksheet.  I add a command Workbooks("File.xlsm").Activate   before Workbooks command and it works.  But  my next command with a variable instead of the name  (this is the second workbook opened),                                                Set xAnnexF = Workbooks(FilenameOnly).Worksheets("SQI-GQI status").Range("D7:D28")  gives a type mismatch

Comment: Declaration is done outside at the top of the code after explicit

Comment: This is not what I was asking about. Where does it take you if you position the caret on the `Range` in `Dim CheckAnnex As Range` and press Shift+F2, and where does it take you if position the caret on the `CheckAnnex` in `set CheckAnnex = Workbooks("File.xlsm").Worksheets("Main").Range("H7:H28")` and press Shift+F2?

Comment: I think I need to recheck all the code.  Thanks a lot for your help.  It seems that some class or element from the other WorkSheet which is not mine is interfering.